# JOptionPane doesn't print formatted Strings

Tags: java, string, swing, formatting, joptionpane

I want to display information in following pattern on output dialog box using a `JOptionPane`.

```
ID        Name                               CH   Marks     Grade     
cse133    Object Oriented Programing         3    80        A         
cse123    Discrete Maths                     2    90        A
```

I read about `String.format` and tried this:

```
public void viewAllCourses(){
    String header=String.format("%-10s%-35s%-5s%-10s%-10s\n","ID","Name","CH","Marks","Grade");
    String output="";
    ArrayList course= new ArrayList();
    for(int i= 0;i<this.courses.size();i++)
    {
        String parts[]=this.courses.get(i).toString().split("  ");
        String grade= this.courses.get(i).getGrade();
        course.add(String.format("%-10s%-35s%-5s%-10s%-10s\n",parts[0],parts[1],parts[2],parts[3],grade));
       output=output+course.get(i);
    }
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, header+output, "View All Course", 1, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

But the option pane ignores formatted strings and shows something like this:

```
ID        Name       CH   Marks     Grade     
cse133    Object Oriented Programing         3    80        A         
cse123    Discrete Maths        2    90        A
```

And last thing that I tried is using `JTable`, I don't know how it works but tried and am having error:

```
String[] cols={"ID","Name","CH","Marks","Grade"};
 Object[][] data;
    for(int i= 0;i<this.courses.size();i++)
    {

        String parts[]=this.courses.get(i).toString().split("  ");
        String grade= this.courses.get(i).getGrade();
        data={{parts[0]+parts[1],parts[2],parts[3],grade}};
    }
    JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
}
```

Comment: `JOptionPane ` isn't ignoring it. Simply you aren't using a monospaced font, so each letter has its own width, so you won't be able to properly see your data as a table. It works with command line because it uses a monospaced font, it won't work with `JOptionPane` unless you change the font manually. If you need to display a table you could use a `JTable` instead.

Comment: *"I want to display information in following pattern on output dialog box using JOptionPane"* I'd use either a `JTable` or HTML for that. *"i tried is using JTable , I don't know how it works but tried and am having error:"* What error? Copy/paste it. General tip: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).